# MVVM: Force ComboBox labels to refresh

Tags: c#, mvvm, data-binding, combobox

I have a ComboBox bound to an `ObservableCollection<IDrive>`

The problem is that `IDrive` does not support `INotifyPropertyChange` nor should it.

While the number of elements in my ComboBox is fixed and does not change, the labels shown in the ComboBox can and will change.

How do I get these labels to update?

Firing `PropertyChanged` on my ObservableCollection does not refresh the content of the labels but it does reset the `SelectedItem` which is a side-effect I don't even want.

Here's my current XAML:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Drives}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDrive}"
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" DisplayMemberPath="Label"
          Margin="5,5,5,5" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
```

`Label` being the property in my `IDrive` interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to wrap the items in a `DriveViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged` and have that repeat the relevant properties. And somehow trigger the changed event from that.

On second thought, I'm not sure if DisplayMemberPath picks up on this. You'll probably need an ItemTemplate as well.

Comment: Yeah it worked. IDrive has now a wrapper with a Label property and when PropertyChanged is fired, the label gets updated. Thanks :)